# Resource not accessible by integration - Using Github App

Tags: github, github-actions

i'm using a token provided by github app, following this tutorial

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/get-an-app-token-in-an-actions-workflow

I provided all possible permissions, but always receive this message: Resource not accessible by integration

There is some another permission that i need to provide?

job on github actions:

```
       - name: Get token
         id: get_token
         uses: machine-learning-apps/actions-app-token@master
              with:
                APP_PEM: ${{ secrets.DANGER_APP_PEM }}
                APP_ID: ${{ secrets.DANGER_APP_ID }}

        - name: Get App Installation Token
          run: |
            echo "This token is masked: ${TOKEN}"
          env: 
            TOKEN: ${{ steps.get_token.outputs.app_token }}
```

im using this in a dangerjs context, so:

```
     - name: Danger
       run: npx danger ci --dangerfile=./scripts/dangerfile.js
        env:
         GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ steps.get_token.outputs.app_token }}
```

[returns this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxjj8.png)

[Github App Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yis2r.png)

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I just added the code and the prints too @rethab